# Get submit button id for query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a master page in witch more then 30 button like (java,asp,php,sql,c,c++,etc...)
and a have a table of questions. All questions are tagged with one subject like asp,java,etc.

I want to get data according to the click button. 
How is it possible?

```
protected void BindRepeaterData()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from question", con);
    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    RepDetails.DataSource = ds;
    RepDetails.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

(I think one page for one button is not a good idea.)

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to capture button click inside Data such as Repeater, GridView, ListView.

Easiest way is to use ***Command*** event instead of *Click* event.

```
<%-- Let say this button is located inside Repeater control.--%>
<asp:Button ID="DoSomethingButton" runat="server" Text="Home"
    OnCommand="DoSomethingButton_Command" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("Id") %>" />

// Retrieve e.CommandArgument from code-behind.
protected void DoSomethingButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Comment: You need to use single quotes inside a Data repeating Control `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `ID` of the button itself, you can cast the sender back to the Button and get it's ID.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button button = sender as Button;
   string id = button.ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you could select field from the table according to button information for example in this way. And you could use same event handler for different buttons. Hope this helps.

```
    protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        string question = readData(button.Text);
        //do further actions
    }

    private string readData(string subject)
    {
        string question = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(/*connection_string*/))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT question from question_table where subject = @subject", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", subject);
                con.Open();
                object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (o != null){
                    question = o.ToString();
                }
                con.Close();

            }
        }
        return question;
    }
```